# How to upload from a local disk and send files via email at Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email-attachments

Someone knows how to upload and send files in Laravel. I can only send regular messages. To upload and send via email always fails. I have tried but always not found the problem.

**SendEmail.php**

```
public $ni;
public $nam;
public $alamat_seko;
public $jud;
public $pes;
public $storagePath;

public function __construct($nis,$nama,$alamat_sekolah,$judul,$pesan,$storagePath)
{
    set_time_limit(8000000);

    $this->ni = $nis;
    $this->nam = $nama;
    $this->alamat_seko = $alamat_sekolah;
    $this->jud = $judul;
    $this->pes = $pesan;
    $this->attachmentFile = public_path() . '/' . $storagePath;
}

public function build()
{
    $e_nis = $this->ni;
    $e_nama = $this->nam;
    $e_alamat_sekolah = $this->alamat_seko;
    $e_judul = $this->jud;
    $e_pesan = $this->pes;
    return $this
    ->view('permohonan.template_mail', compact("e_pesan"))
    ->subject($e_judul)
    ->attach($this->attachmentFile);
}
```

**MailController.php**

```
public function home()
{
    return view('permohonan.index');
}

public function sendemail(Request $get)
{
    $this->validate($get,[
        "email"=>"required",
        "nis"=>"required",
        "nama"=>"required",
        "alamat_sekolah"=>"required",
        "judul"=>"required",
        "pesan"=>"required",
    ]);

    $email = $get->email;
    $nis = $get->nis;
    $nama = $get->nama;
    $alamat_sekolah = $get->alamat_sekolah;
    $judul = $get->judul;
    $pesan = $get->pesan;
    $attachment = Student::findOrFail($get->id);
    $storagePath = Storage::url($attachment->attachmentPath);

    Session::flash("success");
    Mail::to($email)->send( new SendEmail($nis,$nama,$alamat_sekolah,$judul,$pesan,$storagePath));
    return back();
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```php
<form action="{{ url('send/email') }}" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @if (session()->has("success"))
        @include('message.message')
    @endif
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control
            cc-number identified visa" id="file" name="attachment" type="file" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" id="payment-button" type="submit">
            <span id="payment-button-amount">Kirim</span>
            <span id="payment-button-sending" style="display:none;">Sending…</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('permohonan', 'MailController@home')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('send/email', 'MailController@sendemail')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your code here, post it as text, it's easy for us to read and test.

Comment: @catcon 
I am sorry.

Comment: Can you post the result of `dd($attachment->attachmentPath)` please

Comment: @atymic I can't even have used several times
dd ($attachment->attachmentPath)

Comment: What is the result of that?

Comment: Add it after the ` $attachment = Student::findOrFail($get->id);` line

Comment: @atymic I have followed what you said. But nothing happened.

        $attachment = Student::findOrFail($get->id);
        dd($attachment->attachmentPath);
        $storagePath = Storage::url($attachment->attachmentPath);

Comment: That means that line of code must not be being executed.

Comment: For the use of dd () it remains unreadable in the browser. Sorry I'm still learning to use Laravel.

Comment: but if I use this method it can
       -> view ('permohonan.template_mail', compact ("e_pesan"))
        -> subject ($ e_judul)
        -> attachData ($ this-> pdf, 'surat.pdf', [
            'mime' => 'application / pdf',
        ]);

but the files that have been emailed after downloading are only 0kb in size